# Is the @ symbol required for an email address for it to be considered RFC compliant?

Tags: javascript, email, email-validation, rfc, rfc822

My javascript code I found lets through email addresses that dont have an @ symbol in the string, is that ok or is that bad?

Comment: Yes, it is required. And yes, it is very bad. - http://simonslick.com/VEAF/

Comment: An email address without `@`  is sent to the local computer, which is useless in a web settting.

Answer (score 1):

In [RFC 822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html), p.27,  an address is defined by

```
addr-spec   =  local-part "@" domain        ; global address
```

So definitely, you need the "@" character.